# fast way to find occurrences in a list in python

Tags: python

I have a set of unique words called `h_unique`. I also have a 2D list of documents called `h_tokenized_doc` which has a structure like:

```
[ ['hello', 'world', 'i', 'am'], 
  ['hello', 'stackoverflow', 'i', 'am'], 
  ['hello', 'world', 'i', 'am', 'mr'], 
  ['hello', 'stackoverflow', 'i', 'am', 'pycahrm'] ]
```

and `h_unique` as:

```
('hello', 'world', 'i', 'am', 'stackoverflow', 'mr', 'pycharm')
```

what I want is to find the occurrences of the unique words in the tokenized documents list.
So far I came up with this code but this seems to be **VERY** slow. Is there any efficient way to do this?

```
term_id = []
for term in h_unique:
    print term
    for doc_id, doc in enumerate(h_tokenized_doc):
        term_id.append([doc_id for t in doc if t == term])
```

In my case I have a document list of 7000 documents, structured like:

```
[ [doc1], [doc2], [doc3], ..... ]
```

Comment: Yeah, i totally forgot to paste in the code. Updated it.

Comment: You are appending `doc`, which is not a single word; it is a sublist of `h_tokenized_doc`.  And you're appending it `for t in doc` times.  Did you mean to do this?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo

Comment: Still, you're not appending `doc_id` once; you're appending the _same_ `doc_id` many times.  Did you intend to do that?

Comment: yes. I actually want a list that contains the document ids of the terms.

Comment: You're appending _the same_ `doc_id` many times.

Comment: You can reduce time complexity from `O(n^3)` to `O(n^2)` by converting `h_unique` to a `set`.

Comment: Python has a builtin type called `set` that comes with fast operations for comparing sets, use this instead of python `list`.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes because a single term may appear in multiple docs like in the above case for `hello` the result is `[0,1, 2, 3]` and for `world` it is `[0, 2]`

Comment: h_unique is already a set.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Can the lists in your actual case contain more than one item, meaning, can you have a list with two items like: `[ [doc1, doc2] ,... ]` ?

Comment: You can speed it up using 1)A single for loop 2)Dictinoaries/Sets. See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll be slow because you're running through your entire document list once for every unique word. Why not try storing the unique words in a dictionary and appending to it for each word found?

```
unique_dict = {term: [] for term in h_unique}
for doc_id, doc in enumerate(h_tokenized_doc):
    for term_id, term in enumerate(doc):
        try:
            # Not sure what structure you want to keep it in here...
            # This stores a tuple of the doc, and position in that doc
            unique_dict[term].append((doc_id, term_id))
        except KeyError:
            # If the term isn't in h_unique, don't do anything
            pass
```

This runs through all the document's only once.

From your above example, `unique_dict` would be:

```
{'pycharm': [], 'i': [(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)], 'stackoverflow': [(1, 1), (3, 1)], 'am': [(0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)], 'mr': [(2, 4)], 'world': [(0, 1), (2, 1)], 'hello': [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)]}
```

(Of course assuming the typo `'pycahrm'` in your example was deliberate)

Comment: it is a very efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

`term_id.append([doc_id for t in doc if t == term])`

This will not append one `doc_id` for each matching term; it will append an entire list of potentially many *identical* values of `doc_id`.  Surely you did not mean to do this.

Based on your sample code, `term_id` ends up as this:

`[[0], [1], [2], [3], [0], [], [2], [], [0], [1], [2], [3], [0], [1], [2], [3], [], [1], [], [3], [], [], [2], [], [], [], [], []]`

Is this really what you intended?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, and based on your comment to the question where you say

> yes because a single term may appear in multiple docs like in the above case for hello the result is [0,1, 2, 3] and for world it is [0, 2]

it looks like what you wanna do is: For each of the words in the `h_unique` list (which, as mentioned, should be a `set`, or keys in a `dict`, which both have a search access of `O(1)`), go through all the lists contained in the `h_tokenized_doc` variable and find the indexes in which of those lists the word appears.

**IF** that's actually what you want to do, you could do something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

h_tokenized_doc = [['hello', 'world', 'i', 'am'],
                   ['hello', 'stackoverflow', 'i', 'am'],
                   ['hello', 'world', 'i', 'am', 'mr'],
                   ['hello', 'stackoverflow', 'i', 'am', 'pycahrm']]

h_unique = ['hello', 'world', 'i', 'am', 'stackoverflow', 'mr', 'pycharm']

# Initialize a dict with empty lists as the value and the items 
# in h_unique the keys
results = {k: [] for k in h_unique}

for i, line in enumerate(h_tokenized_doc):
    for k in results:
        if k in line:
            results[k].append(i)
print results
```

Which outputs:

`{'pycharm': [], 'i': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'stackoverflow': [1, 3],
 'am': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'mr': [2], 'world': [0, 2],
 'hello': [0, 1, 2, 3]}`

The idea is using the `h_unique` list as keys in a dictionary (the `results = {k: [] for k in h_unique}` part).

Keys in dictionaries have the advantage of a constant lookup time, which is great for the `if k in line:` part (if it were a list, that `in` would take `O(n)`) and then check if the word (the key `k`) appears in the list. If it does, append the index of the **`list`** within the **`matrix`** to the dictionary of results.

Although I'm not certain this is what you want to achieve, though.

Comment: When you say _docs_, are you reading files? Because I've tried your code with approximately 10.000 lists in the matrix (in your question you have 4 lists in `h_tokenized_doc`, I created an `h_tokenized_doc` with 10.000 entries, is what I mean) and it takes... nothing. Maybe you should consider opening another question showing a closer use-case to your actual scenario?

Comment: sorry that comment was a mistake.. sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize your code to do the trick with

1. Using just a single for loop
2. Generators  dictionaries for constant lookup time, as suggested previously. Generators are faster than for loops because the generate values **on the fly**

   ```
   In [75]: h_tokenized_doc = [ ['hello', 'world', 'i', 'am'], 
       ...:   ['hello', 'stackoverflow', 'i', 'am'], 
       ...:   ['hello', 'world', 'i', 'am', 'mr'], 
       ...:   ['hello', 'stackoverflow', 'i', 'am', 'pycahrm'] ]

   In [76]: h_unique = ('hello', 'world', 'i', 'am', 'stackoverflow', 'mr', 'pycharm')

   In [77]: term_id = {k: [] for k in h_unique}

   In [78]: for term in h_unique:
       ...:     term_id[term].extend(i for i in range(len(h_tokenized_doc)) if term in h_tokenized_doc[i])
   ```

   which yields the output

   ```
   {'am': [0, 1, 2, 3],
    'hello': [0, 1, 2, 3],
    'i': [0, 1, 2, 3],
    'mr': [2],
    'pycharm': [],
    'stackoverflow': [1, 3],
    'world': [0, 2]}
   ```

A more descriptive solution would be

```
In [79]: for term in h_unique:
    ...:     term_id[term].extend([(i,h_tokenized_doc[i].index(term)) for i in range(len(h_tokenized_doc)) if term in h_tokenized_doc[i]])


In [80]: term_id
Out[80]: 
{'am': [(0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)],
 'hello': [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)],
 'i': [(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)],
 'mr': [(2, 4)],
 'pycharm': [],
 'stackoverflow': [(1, 1), (3, 1)],
 'world': [(0, 1), (2, 1)]}
```

Comment: It takes about 10 minutes on my set of 7000 documents

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) How fast was the best solution?

Comment: It took about 600 ms

Comment: Woah! That's some real upgrade. Thanks for the heads up :-)